# Vector Public in Class - Can't Use in Implementation?

Tags: c++, class, vector

Here's my situation. I have a class in which I have defined a vector publicly, as below:

```
class TrackObjects
{
public:

    vector<MovingObj> movingObjects;

...
```

etc.

It has a constructor and everything. I have a separate .cpp file with some implementations where I'm trying to use that vector and methods on that vector. As one example, it's part of a condition in a function like so:

```
if (movingObjects.locX >= x1)
```

...

etc.

It tells me movingObjects is undeclared, and to first use this function. It's not a function, and to my knowledge, I haven't called it like one/tried to use it like one.

Can anyone suggest why I might be getting this error?

**EDIT:** locX is a public variable in the another class MovingObj. TrackObj is the class that creates the vector for objects MovingObj creates. Sorry, I really should've specified that. Like so:

class MovingObj {

public:

MovingObj(int inId, int inLocX, int inLocY, int inWidth, int inHeight);

int id, locX, locY,width,height;

Comment: Where does the name `locX` come from, is it a field of `MovingObj` ?

Comment: I dunno about *your* `std::vector<>`, but the official one has no member named `locX`, so you may wanna rethink what you're doing.

Comment: is the function you're using it a member function of `TrackObjects`?

Comment: also, I'm not sure you understand what a vector is

Comment: `movingObjects` is a `vector` of objects of the `MovingObj` class. This *vector* does not have any data member `locX` like you attempt to use in the line `movingObjects.locX`. What would work, for example, is `movingObjects[0].locX` to access `locX` of the first `MovingObj` instance in the `vector` (assuming it is not empty, of course).

Comment: Elsewhere I tried 

vector <MovingObj>::iterator beginIt = movingObjects.begin();

With the same error. It is a vector, so why the error?

Comment: Probably because you are trying to access `movingObjects` outside of a `TrackObjects` member function. This does not work, as I explained in my answer. You would need a `TrackObjects` object to access its `movingObjects` data member.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. As it is not part of a member function, even though it's public, it needs an object to interface it with the class, since it itself is an object of another class? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you are telling us, the proper way to access locX would be something along the lines of:

```
TrackObjects objs;
objs.movingObjects[15].locX = 123.45;
```

Or, maybe:

```
if(objs.movingObjects[15].locX >= 15)
{
    //do something
}
```

You can also encapsulate your access method in TrackObjects (put this in your TrackObjects.cpp implementation):

```
bool TrackObjects::testLocX(int pos)
{
if(movingObjects[pos].locX>=15)
   return true;
return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an elementary C++ issue. movingObjects is part of an object.  Code that is not part of the TrackObjects class can only access movingObjects by specifying which object's movingObjects you wish to access.

if (someobject.movingObjects.size() > 0)
   ...

Another issue is that to access such an object from another cpp file you will first have to #include the file that contains the class definition.